# SVN Repository Newbie Questions

Tags: php, javascript, flash, svn, repository

I am in my early stages of understanding an SVN repository, and I had a few questions:

1. What kind of files should I put in a repository? For example, I know PHP, JS, FLA, etc... are  accepted as standard, but what about things liks PSDs (which may be changed in the future), AIs (Adobe Illustrator files), etc...? Should I save those in the repository, or just the exported version?
2. Are there files that are considered "too big" to put in a repository? For example, I have a PSD which is 11 mB.
3. What is the maxmium recommended file size? If it matters, I am running this repository within my environment, so storage isn't a problem. :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Generally, put everything in.  However, you might want to separate files by type so you can check out your PHP/JS etc. without having to also check out hundreds of megs of PSDs as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Frank! Good to know that I can practically put anything in there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll respond to your questions in order.

1. Any file that you change frequently and would like to have backed up is a good candidate for going in an SVN repository. If you'll ever want to be able to "go back to last Tuesday's version" or something along those lines, you should probably put the file in SVN. To contrast, music and movies are poor candidates for SVN control, since you're not very likely to change them (unless you're a producer or film editor, of course).
2. SVN is a differential backup system, meaning it sends only the differences between the new and old files you create. For example, if you add a line to a 3,000-line text file and commit it, only that last line will be sent over the network. So, there is no real limit on file size (apart from those imposed by your bandwidth and host, of course). I've personally tracked a 100 MB file before. Also, keep in mind that the whole differential tracking is great for text files, but not so great on binary files (DOC, PDF, FLA, PSD, etc.) In these cases, you can still use SVN, but you will probably send close to the whole file size every time.
3. As I said before, I wouldn't worry about changing the size of your files for SVN's sake; it's pretty versatile.

Comment: awesome, Zach!!! This answer will allow me to move forward with my project development. Wish I could give you more points than just an up-vote and an accepted answer. :D Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: No problem; I'm glad I could help. Also, take a look at Frank Farmer's comment. If you're doing web development work, I highly recommend adding a "local" folder that contains your PSD/FLA files, since those tend to be large. That way, you can commit your smaller text files without the larger ones getting in the way.

Comment: I agree with all of this, most of the time I create 2 root folders: online and offline. All the sources (psd, fla, word docs, specs...) go into offline